How do you one hot encode a column that exists in multiple pandas dataframes?
I have ten dataframes of event level data from ten different hockey seasons that each have a couple columns that I'd like to one hot encode with the intention of training a model on the historical data to make predictions about this years data . My current issue is that that columns that need to be encoded don't contain all possible values in each dataframe. Just as an example there have been some expansion teams added, so dataframes for earlier years would not have these teams and thus they would not have an encoded column.
The first thing I tried was concatenating all ten dataframes and doing my one hot encoding that way, but my dataframe became too big and my jupyter notebook kernel kept dying. So now I've decided to try to approach each dataframe separately, but this creates the problem for me that I explained above and I've had a tough time finding a solution. Here's an example of what I'm looking for. I would like Table 1 and Table 2 to be one hot encoded as follows.
Table 1



Team
year




A
1


B
1



Table 2



Team
year




B
2


C
2



Table 1 one hot encoded



Team
year
A
B
C




A
1
1
0
0


B
1
0
1
0



Table 2 one hot encoded



Team
year
A
B
C




B
2
0
1
0


C
2
0
0
1



So essentially the question is, how can I get that "C" column in Table 1 and that "A" column in Table 2, since those values don't exist in those tables.

You’ll need to ensure that you have a collection of all the unique teams across both DataFrames and work from there.
Then you can either…
A. run pandas.get_dummies on the 'team' column, then .reindex the missing teams into the result
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'team': ['a', 'b'], 'year': [1, 1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'team': ['b', 'c'], 'year': [2, 2]})
teams = np.union1d(df1['team'].unique(), df2['team'].unique())

df1_encoded = pd.get_dummies(df1['team']).reindex(columns=teams, fill_value=False).astype(int)
df2_encoded = pd.get_dummies(df2['team']).reindex(columns=teams, fill_value=False).astype(int)

print(df1.join(df1_encoded))
#   team  year  a  b  c
# 0    a     1  1  0  0
# 1    b     1  0  1  0

print(df2.join(df2_encoded))
#   team  year  a  b  c
# 0    b     2  0  1  0
# 1    c     2  0  0  1

B. convert the team columns to a Categorical, pandas.get_dummies will provide the correct results
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'team': ['a', 'b'], 'year': [1, 1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'team': ['b', 'c'], 'year': [2, 2]})

# Convert each Team column to a Categorical that share the same categories
TeamsDtype = pd.CategoricalDtype(
    np.union1d(df1['team'].unique(), df2['team'].unique())
)
df1['team'] = df1['team'].astype(TeamsDtype)
df2['team'] = df2['team'].astype(TeamsDtype)

# `get_dummies` *works* now with no extra contortion
df1_encoded = pd.get_dummies(df1['team']).astype(int)
df2_encoded = pd.get_dummies(df2['team']).astype(int)

print(df1.join(df1_encoded))
#   team  year  a  b  c
# 0    a     1  1  0  0
# 1    b     1  0  1  0

print(df2.join(df2_encoded))
#   team  year  a  b  c
# 0    b     2  0  1  0
# 1    c     2  0  0  1

I recommend the latter, Categorical approach if you are going to be holding onto the 'team' column
in its original form as the Categorical encoding will speed up any comparison operation and reduce the memory footprint of your data.

Perfect, this did just what I needed, really should've thought of that. Thanks so much!
